# Is the focus on Magic a problem? Is there anything to do about it?

Tags: discussion, magic-the-gathering

Disclaimer - I'm the founder of [Draw3Cards](http://draw3cards.com/), originally a Stack Exchange 1.0 site. I'm not an avid user of Boardgames SE, and have recently stopped paying attention to Draw3Cards as well, in favor of other projects.

[magic-the-gathering](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering) has as many questions as the next 6 tags combined. Is this a problem? That is, does it make BCG too much of a Magic Site, without really being a site dedicated to Magic? Does BCG adequately serve the MtG community?

Comment: Use the Favourite / Ignore Tags function, end of problem?

Comment: MtG has so much more published content (and rules that are so much more complicated) than any other single game on the sight, it would be absolutely shocking if it didn't dominate the number of questions. This isn't a problem, this is an accurate reflection of the real-world board-and-card-game ecology.

Comment: Also, I've (heavily) edited the question to make it seem less leading/opinionated/inflammatory. The OP sounds like he has his own answer, I'd encourage him to add it as an answer rather than put it in the question.

Comment: My intention was not to promote D3C, but rather to ask "Would B&CG viable without Magic? Is it a good idea to *rely* on Magic? My thesis has always been that Magic deserves its own Q&A site, and I don't know if B&CG does  or does not, but that shouldn't interfere with an independent SE Magic site. Anyway I think discussions and thoughts are good, I don't claim to have the one single answer to the questions I posed.

Comment: @PatLudwig is correct that Area51 is the place to debate an independent SE Magic site. If you have issues or comments on how we *do* handle magic questions here, we'll listen to *constructive feedback*, or even just identification of problems. Presupposing that Magic questions should be somewhere else, however, won't get you far with a group of users that happily ask and answer Magic questions on this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Demonstrate an actual problem instead of a nebulous concern.**

**"Magic is a popular topic" is not a problem.** This is like complaining that Stackoverflow has a lot of questions about C#, or that RPG.SE is dominated by D&D-related questions. MTG isn't crowding out the other games.

**"B&CG makes a dedicated site seem less necessary" is not a problem.** Or, rather, it's not a problem for B&CG. It may be a problem for that dedicated site. But that's part of the test a focused site has to pass in order to succeed in the first place. There are lots of tech-specific little spinoffs. Chess and Poker have beta SEs but we never went out of our way to ban those questions on B&CG.

---

Does B&CG adequately serve the MTG community?

Well, for starters, it serves the MTG community way more adequately than a B&CG site that tried to discourage Magic questions would. Our rules answers are timely and accurate. The volume of strategic discussion here is limited, but the strategy answers excellently relate a specific situation back to theory and fundamentals — which, in my honest opinion, is much better than what I've seen on many dedicated Magic sites.

And MTG is clearly a net benefit to B&CG as a whole — not just in terms of traffic and community but in how it drives the overall culture: low-speculation answers that rigorously cite rules whenever possible. You'll see MTG pop up a fair bit in the general game-design answers, as well, because it's one of those games whose individual elements contain a lot of different examples of mechanical interplay.

Answer (score 7):

**No**, the fact that MtG has six times the number of questions isn't an issue. BG.SE is an expert board game Q&A site, the distribution of questions has no bearing on its purpose.

BG.SE serves the MtG community well. It is rare that an answer is given that is incorrect, and when it is there are enough rules experts that the correct answers are quickly referenced (and upvoted) and the wrong answers are downvoted.

If you believe it is, it has a simple solution...

**Ask more non-MtG questions.**